# Any good smartcontract for "business calendar" oracles?

Tags: oracles

is anybody aware of some smart-contract that can be used as external "trustable" oracle for no-so-simple scenarios, like for example calculating the number of non-festive days passed since a given date or time-windows.

I'm thinking of some external (trusted) entity that is allowed to fill such calendar and sign when a new day has passed, ...

I'm thinking about use-cases like:
- Some smart-contract internal state change or some payment must be allowed just after 10 working days, excluding weekends.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle sounds complicated and gas gushing approach.

I suggest this:

- A special transaction parameter be generated and signed by your own server
- The server calculates the days
- The information is passed into the smart contract in the transaction payload, as a function parameter
- The smart contract verifies that the result is honest by checking the signature of the parameter, so that it was your server that made the calculation

However, for better judgement, I kindly ask you to edit your question and add more background information about your business case.

Answer (score 2):

Chainlink may be what you’re looking for: https://chain.link